# How to align section and footer to the left of sidenav?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to html and css. I'm practicing building html layouts and I'm having a little difficulty. I can't figure out how to align the footer and section to the left of nav. These always overlap with correct percentage widths. Why does this happen?

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}

section {
  background: red;
  display: block;
  width: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

footer {
  background: green;
  display: block;
  width: 70%;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

nav {
  display: block;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav class="sidebar">
  <!-- Put Here content of sidebar -->
  Content example
  </nav>
  
  <section>
  <!-- Put Here content of section -->
  Content example
  </section>
</body>

<footer>
  Content example
</footer>
```

Comment: Hi GorillaDev, I would suggest that you don't use absolute positioning for these kind of elements. This is easy done in other ways. I recommend that you read basic html/css tutorials to grasp the basics. What source of learning do you have now?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Actually no source of learning. I am passionate about coding and I learn self-taught.

Comment: Keep it up. I would recommend to learn [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/). If you like video content for learning I would recommend two awesome instructors both with great content. For flexbox: [Kevin Powells Learn flexbox the easy way](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u044iM9xsWU) or [Wes Bos flexbox series](https://flexbox.io). For grid you can check both [Kevin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rg7Fvvl3taU) and [Wes](https://cssgrid.io). Happy learning and good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `position: absolute`, you can use `display: grid`

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: gray;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

main {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  place-content: space-between;
  grid-template-columns: 30% 70%;
  grid-template-areas: "nav section" "nav footer";
}

section {
  background: red;
  grid-area: section;
  height: 50px;
}

footer {
  background: green;
  padding: 20px;
  grid-area: footer;
  height: 50px;
}

nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <nav class="sidebar">
    <!-- Put Here content of sidebar -->
    Content example
  </nav>

  <section>
    <!-- Put Here content of section -->
    Content example
  </section>

  <footer>
    Content example
  </footer>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Curiosity, the symbol `*` is used to indicate that the css rules apply to everything?

Comment: yes. it's called the universal selector

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}

section {
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 4vh;
}

footer {
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4vh;
}

nav {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  height: 20vh;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}

spacer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 12vh;
  display: inline-block;
}

html,
body,
nav,
section,
footer {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<nav class="sidebar">
  <!-- Put Here content of sidebar -->
  nav
</nav><!--
--><div>
  <section>
    <!-- Put Here content of section -->
    section
  </section>
  <spacer>&nbsp;</spacer>
  <footer>
    footer
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. Don't just dump code and expect everyone to understand it